# how safe it is using many Paypal IPNs on same hosting

Tags: php, paypal

I've made a pay to play script for some online game, basically many people will want this script but giving away files is bad idea because at end of all it will be shared.

What I plan to do is keeping the script on my host and make subfolders with script copy for each online server owner that will use the payment script.

game1 for example has one game project data, game2 is totaly different one

sample.com/game1/

sample.com/game2/

Now my question is, is it safe having Paypal IPN file in each subfolder for different project? (different configs and paypal owners also of course).

Or maybe i should create 1 single IPN that will recognize who people paid to?
Any suggestions will help. Thank you for attention

Answer (score 0):

Safe, sure, but it would be more difficult to manage them all and keep them all separately maintained.  The use of Git/Composer could make that easier, but I'd still recommend just hosting a single IPN solution and writing logic to recognize who it's for like you mentioned.